# Double cookie in Request.Cookies

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

I have a following code in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["AUTH"] != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies["AUTH"].Value);

        HttpContext.Current.User = new MyPrincipal(ticket.Name);

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["AUTH"];
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

It works fine, but when i've checked the Request.Cookies collection, there were 2 entries for AUTH cookie, with different values. How come?

This is the code of the authentication process in login page:

```
if (Account.Authenticate(login.Text, pass.Text))
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.Text, true, 43200);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("AUTH");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


    Response.Redirect(Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Application_AuthenticateRequest routine you seem to be accessing the existing cookie using *'HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["AUTH"];'* but then adding another one using *'Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);'*.

You could either remove the last line as you do not need to add another cookie when you already have it present in the collection. Alternatively add a Remove before the Add in order to get rid of the existing named cookie from the collection before adding it back again.

Comment: I want to modify the expiration date of the cookie. As i understand, the Response.Cookies Collection is empty and when I add smth into it, the application just adds a header "set-cookie blah blah blah"... Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Use:

```
Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

`Add` allows duplicates. `Set` does not, so it can be used to update an existing cookie.